# Packing Source Code and Dependencies

Tags: java, maven

I am trying to build a jar package using Maven with source code and all dependencies. The problem is that Maven is no packing the source code only the dependencies.

Do I need to set a configuration to pack the source code too?

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>courier-perf-test</groupId>
    <artifactId>courier-perf-test</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>ze.delivery.HTTPRequestClass</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>make-assembly</id> <!-- this is used for inheritance merges -->
                        <phase>package</phase> <!-- bind to the packaging phase -->
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json -->
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.googlecode.json-simple/json-simple -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use src as the descriptorRef in your assembly-plugin configuration to create source archives for your project or it might be better to use the predefined descriptor `project`:

```
<descriptorRefs>
   <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
   <descriptorRef>src</descriptorRef>
</descriptorRefs>
```

OR:

```
<descriptorRefs>
   <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
   <descriptorRef>project</descriptorRef>
</descriptorRefs>
```

Reference: [maven-assembly-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/descriptor-refs.html)